# How to find which file block contains the data?

Tags: memory-management, offset

I'm stuck on the problem below. I do not understand what exactly its looking for. The previous assignment I had made me find the physical address. Is that related to this? 
Determine which file block(not disk block) contains the data at the following file offsets if the block size is 8Kb: 
a. 1
b. 8188
c. 8192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like it's saying:

- You have a file consisting of blocks of 8kB (let's assumed they're numbered blocks 0,1,2,etc.
- Give me the number of the block that byte at offset 1 falls into
- Give me the number of the block that byte at offset 8188 falls into
- Give me the number of the block that byte at offset 8192 falls into

If this is what the question means then it's trivial, and I'm not going to spoil your homework with a free answer.

Comment: When you worded it like that it actually made sense to me. Thus the 1 would fall into the 1st block. 8188 would fall into the 1023rd block and 8188 would fall into the 1024th block. That is correct right?

Comment: No, it's not right.  Work out how many bytes there are in 8kB.

Comment: Okay, there's 8192 bytes in 8 kB.

Comment: Could you please explain at least the one of them? I am not trying to get free answers I am trying to understand it. It may be clear as day to you, but for some reason I'm not seeing the logic.

Comment: 8188 falls into the first block, because it's < 8192

Comment: Ah thank you. So 1 would also fall into the first block, while 8192 would go to the second block since it isn't less than 8192.